# Edit existing Extjs List

Tags: javascript, php, web, extjs, shopware

I try to edit some Shopware Extjs Cells from a Grid View but my overriding doesn't work.

I tried to override the cells with the dataIndex. My goal is to override the status cells from Shopware and put a background color on these cells. (red background).

```
//{block name="backend/order/view/list/list"}
//{$smarty.block.parent}
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.OrderColor.view.lit.List', {
    override: 'Shopware.apps.Order.view.list.List',

getColumns: function () {

    var me = this;

    var columns = me.callOverridden(arguments);

    var ColorColumn = {
        dataIndex: 'status',
        flex: 1,
        align: 'center',
        sortable: false,
        renderer: function () {
            return '<div data-qtip="{s      namespace=backend/order_color/view/list/list name=itemsWithNoStock}Bestellstatus Eins{/s}" id="test" class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="background-color:#dc514d; margin: 0 auto; width: auto; height: 100%; border-radius: 0px;"></div>';
        },
    };
    return Ext.Array.insert(columns, 0 - 1, [ColorColumn]);
}d
});
```

Result: I've got a new column. But I want to overwrite existing ones from Shopware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace the Ext.Array.insert with the Replace.

Ext.Array.replace (columns, 0, 1, [ColorColumn]);

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of column to be replaced, you can just assign new object in that location.
columns[1] = ColorColumn